# P5.JS Using a For loop to draw a centred set of rect's

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to create a grid-like structure in a 3x2 fashion such as below, but I'm looking to centre it to the canvas, and have it scale with the page based on `width` and `height`. I'm looking to do so without using the `scale();` or `resizeCanvas;` functions, and ideally doing it all similar to my current code, if possible. I've tried offsetting and messing with different math, but I just can't seem to get it. My current attempt appears like this; [Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AozX2.png)
This is my code;

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
    background(100);
    rectMode(CENTER);

    let posX = width * 0.5;
    let posY = height * 0.5;
    let sizeX = width / 3;
    let sizeY = height / 3;

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            fill('Red');
            rect(i * posX + 75, j * posY + 75, sizeX - 50, sizeY - 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be also vertically centered or are you interested only on centering it horizontally?

Comment: Also I think that the only way to change the canvas size when the window is resized is to call resizeCanvas() within the function windowResized(). Without doing this, your canvas will remain of the same size even when the window is resized.

Comment: I guess both, I will set the canvas size to look nice after I manage it, but just for scaling purposes probably best to learn both!

Comment: I mean manually changing the 500, 500 after createCanvas, to edit the size! This is for school learning purposes, rather than a practical application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, when trying your code I actually got a different result than the image linked in your question, but it doesn't matter much.
Few things that don't change the result but are of better practice:
1 - If you never change the value of a variable during its scope, better declare is as `const` rather than `let`.
2 - Having `rectMode()` and `fill()` within `draw()` even though their parameters never change is useless and it would be better to use them within `setup()`.
3 - I left `background()` inside `draw()` because it can be useful in the case you want to move the rectangles (or do any other drawing) without seeing the trails of all the drawings made so far.

Now let's come to the solutions I found:
First one, without calling `rectMode()` so that the rectangles are drawn by default from the corner and, as it is shown, there are less calculations to do:

```
function setup()
{
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
}

function draw()
{
    background(100);
    
    //Set the space between the edge of the canvas and your rectangles.
    const offsetX = width/10;
    const offsetY = width/10;
    
    /*
        Set the size of the rectangles so that they are X times smaller the width
        (or height) of the canvas already reduced of the space from the edges,
        where X is the number of rectangles that make up the rows (or columns).
    */
    const sizeX = (width-offsetX*2)/3;
    const sizeY = (height-offsetY*2)/2;

    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(let j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            rect(i*sizeX +offsetX, j*sizeY +offsetY, sizeX, sizeY);
        }
    }
}
```

Second one, setting `rectMode(CENTER)`. It requires a bit more calculations and the call of `rectMode()`, but other than these it doesn't change much (comments are the same so I didn't repeat them):

```
function setup()
{
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
}

function draw()
{
    background(100);
    
    const offsetX = width/10;
    const offsetY = width/10;

    const sizeX = (width-offsetX*2)/3;
    const sizeY = (height-offsetY*2)/2;

    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(let j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            /*
                Add also half of the size so that the offset is from the edge of the
                rectangle and not from the center.
            */
            rect(i*sizeX+offsetX+sizeX/2, j*sizeY+offsetY+sizeY/2, sizeX, sizeY);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you asked for, if you have any question don't hesitate to ask.

**EDIT**

Added a change in color while drawing the rectangle (requested in the comments):

```
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw()
{
    background(100);
    
    const offsetX = width/10;
    const offsetY = width/10;

    const sizeX = (width-offsetX*2)/3;
    const sizeY = (height-offsetY*2)/3;

    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(let j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            fill(colors[i]);
            rect(i*sizeX +offsetX, j*sizeY +offsetY, sizeX, sizeY);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Hi again! I'm trying to plug colour into this loop, but It won't seem to work and I'm wondering if im doing something wrong. My current attempt is to set an array of "red", "green", "blue" and have 2 squares of each once the loop is finished. I made a 3rd for being for(let c = 0; c < 2; c++). It returns nothing and sometimes breaks the page, any help appreciated~

Comment: @swamptiger24 I edited the answer adding the code to do what you asked, let me know if I understood properly.

Comment: Ah, you are fantastic!!! Very much exactly what I was looking for. Would you be able to explain how that array works? I thought I was on the right track is all

Comment: @swamptiger24 The array is created as a const at the start of the code, outside `setup()`, so that its value can be read also inside `draw()`. Then, since we conveniently have as many colors as columns, we access the element using the columns counter (`i`). The order you give to the elements of the array will be the order the colors will be drawn.

Comment: Would you replace (i) with a numeric value if it wasn't conveniently what we needed?

Comment: @swamptiger24 yeah, I would create another variable to change its value independently from `i`. How to change that value is up to you depending on your needs. For example, if the colors were six instead of 3, I would declare another variable `let c = 0` and increment its value every time it's used, like `fill(colors[c++]);`. And of course change the colors array accordingly. Another tip, you can repeat colors with the method illustrated above by repeating the same element when initializing the array.